# Width issue within an absolute positioned container with a scrollbar

Tags: css, width, scrollbar, absolute

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/2hT8R/11/)

My problem is:

If I affect a `max-height` to the absolute positionned `.rc-datalist` container, a scrollbar appears : this is the expected behavior.

BUT the longest child of this container turns wrong : the last characters are hidden under the scrollbar. (I highlighted this line in my jsFiddle)

And when I add a right floated element, it is getting worst, as you can see...

Please, does somebody know how to fix/hack this weird but cross-browser behavior ?
I just want the `.rc-datalist` to be a little bit larger when scrollbar appears.

Information :

- No javascript, only CSS (I sure know how to fix it with javascript)
- `.rc-datalist absolute position` is mandatory and I do not want to specify a numeric width for it.
- The content of the `.rc-option` elements can be changed or wrapped. I just need to keep the parent-child relation between `.rc-datalist` and `.rc-option`s. Within the `.rc-option`s, I don't care, as long as it does the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by my-self.

### [Fixed Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/2hT8R/14/)

By adding :

```
.rc-option:before {
    float :right;
    width:1.5em;
    content:'';
    display:inline-block
}
```

It enlarges each line by default (even if no scrollbar) but keeps the highlighting effect working.

Yes!! I knew it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `white-space:nowrap` from `.rc-option`, leaving:

```
.rc-option {
    padding:0 0.5em;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hT8R/12/)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to tell : I want to keep it in a raw. Is there a way to make the `.rc-datalist` element larger when scroll appears ?

Answer (score -1):

If you have scrolling issue, try `overflow-x : scroll` and `overflow-y : scroll`
If you want to make the hidden text be on top of it's background, try higher `z-index;` such as `z-index:100`

If you the background width of the child is auto, try padding as `padding: 1px`

You can study on these at:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp
```

Comment: Thanks for try to help, but what you suggest does not work at all. Did you try it on the jsFiddle before suggesting ?

Comment: @M'sieurToph' My answer was not intended to provide a prepared piece of cake, rather it was a suggestion. What I suggested, are the common references of CSS that are expected to come handy for the issues like your one. Besides, the study links are given so that you can get further information and try on your codes. The behavior of your code might not be as expected due to CSS of other areas. Thanks.

Comment: I am not a newbie. I know about padding, z-index and so on for years. I tried all pertinent combinations before asking here. My question was a little bit more technical and I confirm : your suggestions do not work (as I thought when reading them).